# guarantee uniqueness of table relationship

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

So I have a table of states.

```
CREATE TABLE public.states(
  state_code  char(2) NOT NULL
);
```

I have several different ways of grouping those states into regions, so I came ups with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.region_type (
  region_type_name varchar NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)
CREATE TABLE public.regions (
  region_id    serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  region_type_name varchar NOT NULL ,
  region_name  varchar NOT NULL,
  /* Keys */
  CONSTRAINT regions_region_name_unq
    UNIQUE (region_name),
  CONSTRAINT regions_region_type_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (region_type_name)
    REFERENCES region_type(region_type_name)
)
CREATE TABLE public.region2state (
  region_id    int4 NOT NULL,
  state_code  char(2) NOT NULL
)
```

Now, the one thing that this does not give me is I would like to guarantee that each state is only related to ONE region of a particular region_type.

E.G. TX can be in the "PADD 3" region (of type 'PADD") and in the "Southwest" region (of the "internal" type), but I'd like to guarantee no one accidentally puts TX in PADD 3 and PADD 2 (both of type PADD).

How would I guarantee that?

Answer (score 1):

You can guarantee this in `region2state`.  Basically, you want each state to appear only once per region.  So, including the region type in `region2state` is handy for this purpose:

```
CREATE TABLE public.region2state (
  region_id        int4    NOT NULL,
  region_type_name varchar NOT NULL,
  state_code       char(2) NOT NULL,

  constraint unq_r2s_regiontype_statecode unique (region_type_name, state_code),
  constraint fk_r2s_regionid_regiontype foreign key (region_id, region_type_name) references regions(region_id, region_type_name)
);
```

For the final foreign key constraint, you need a unique key in `regions` on `(region_id, region_type_name)`.  Although this is redundant (`region_id` is already unique), it ensures that the region and type are compatible between the two tables.

Comment: so the type needs to be replicated in the relation table?  the FK/unique keys on region_id and region_type_name guarantee no mistakes.

Answer (score -1):

The best bet is for your many-to-many table to include the type.  That way you can make the primary key the entire row:

```
CREATE TABLE public.region2state (
  region_id        int4    NOT NULL,
  region_type_name varchar NOT NULL,
  state_code       char(2) NOT NULL,

  primary key(region_id, region_type_name, state_code)
);
```

Personally I'd make the region_type an integer id along with a name but that's your call.

Comment: This would't work.  I could have these two rows in this schema (id's eliminated for clarity:
PADD 3        PADD           TX
PADD 2        PADD           TX